# ObjC runtime: faking block ivars

Tags: objective-c, runtime, block

I wrote this code:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert new];
objc_setAssociatedObject(alert, @"block", aBlock, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
if (![objc_getAssociatedObject(alert, @"block") isEqual:aBlock]) NSLog(@"failure");
```

where `aBlock` is a `void (^)(NSAlert *)` block passed to the function calling the code above. Now: if the block doesn't contain any external `__block` variable, everything goes right, but if it tries to set a such variable (for example, an external `__block NSString *string`) I get the `@"failure"` message. What can I do?

Comment: You should not use a string as the key for `objc_setAssociatedObject()`. Or if you do, at least put it into a static/global variable and re-use the same variable in both places. The reason being the association APIs only care if the *pointer* is the same for the key, it doesn't care about the value. So using a string like that only works if the compiler properly uniques them during compilation, which it is not required to do.

Comment: My favorite trick for defining keys for association APIs is to say `static const void * const kBlockKey = &kBlockKey`. Yes, the variable has its own address as its value. This works, and because it's using its own address as its value, it's practically guaranteed to be unique (which you want so you don't step on someone else's associated objects).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working correctly. A block is not necessarily equal to a copy of itself — it's implementation-dependent. You can simplify it to `if (![aBlock isEqual:[aBlock copy]]) NSLog(@"Failure!")` and you should get the same result.

Comment: Blocks are equal when I don't access any external variable in the block. The problem is that I can't use anymore this mechanism when I access external __block variables.

Comment: I clarified this point. What I should have said is that a block is not *necessarily* equal to itself. This is just a limitation of Objective-C blocks, not really anything about using a block as an ivar.

Comment: @user732274: If you want to figure out if the block is the same, just use `==`.

Comment: @user732274: You don't care about some notion of equality here; equality doesn't make sense for blocks. You care if the actual value is the same, and that's what `==` is for.

Comment: @KevinBallard: That test won't work the way the OP wants either. The intent is for a block to compare equal to a copy of itself, but copying the block produces a new object.

Comment: If I call the block using objc_getAssociatedObject when it accesses external __block variables I get a crash.

Comment: @Chuck: It is? I assumed it was to test if the alert was still associated with the same block. It doesn't make sense to try and test if you're using another block with the same implementation. There's far better ways of doing that.

Comment: I tried that test when I realized I couldn't call my block anymore using the associated one when that block accessed external __block variables...

Comment: @user732274: Thinking about it a bit more, I would bet money that your crasher is due to mismanagement of your `__block` variables. If you're not using ARC, the block will not automatically retain `__block` variables, so you need to take special care to retain and release them appropriately around the block. (This isn't related to the issue of block equality in your question, though. That's still unreliable for the reasons stated in my answer. This is a separate issue.)

Comment: @user732274: Then it is inexplicable given the information you have provided. As I pointed out, I ran your code and it worked. You'll need to give us an actual instance of the bug if you want us to solve the problem.

Comment: The code it's there: it is inside a function which takes that block as a parameter. My code works fine if the block (fetched back using objc_getAssociatedObject) doesn't contain an external variable (and I can run the block without any issue), while it crashes if I run the block when it uses an external __block variable.